# React js html append

Tags: reactjs

I want to build a tree using tree data.
The code what I have written is below

```
 import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import { Draggable, Droppable } from 'react-drag-and-drop';
import './index.css';
const styles = {
  fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
  textAlign: 'center',
};

class App extends React.Component
{
 constructor()
  {
    super();
    this.html=[];
    this.myTreedata=[{
     name : "Phrase",
     id : 1,
     children : [{
       name : "poem",
       id : 2
     }]
   }];
    this.state={
      toggle : true
    }

    this.onDrop=this.onDrop.bind(this);
    this.assign=this.assign.bind(this);
  }
  assign(data)
  {

   data.map(node => {
       this.html.push(<Droppable types={['yolo']} onDrop=
     {this.onDrop}><li id={node.id}><span>{node.name}</span>
       </li></Droppable>);
       if(node.children && node.children.length > 0)
         {

           this.html.push(<ul>);    
           this.assign(node.children);
           this.html.push(</ul>);
         }
       console.log(this.html);
     })
    //console.log(this.html);
  //return html;
  }


  onDrop(data,e)
  {
    this.setState({
      toggle : !this.toggle
    });
    this.myTreedata=[{
     name : "op",
     id : 1,
     children : [{
       name : "poem",
       id : 2,
       children : [{
         name : "poem2",
         id : 3
       }]
     }]
   }];
  }
 render()
  {
    var str=this.myTreedata;

   this.assign(str);
    return (   
  <div>
    <Tree />
     <div className="tree" >
       <ul >
        {this.html}
       </ul>
        </div>
    </div>);

}
}

class Drag extends React.Component 
{
  constructor()
  {
    super();

  }
  render()
  {
   const myTreedata=[{
     name : "phrase",
     id : 1,
     children : [{
       name : "poem",
       id : 2
     }]
   }];
   return(<div><App /></div>);
  }
}

const Tree = () => 
 ( <div>
    <Draggable type="yolo" data="banana">
      <p>Banana</p>
     </Draggable>
    </div>);

render(<Drag />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

But The output what I am getting is not what I wanted.Its not rendering the 
this.html array elements. **Basically I am trying to append html components dynamically**
How do I approach?

Comment: would be is not called?, i've seen definition, but when is called?

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see as that html is an instance property of App

```
this.html
```

When you dynamically update the content of this variable, React is not going to trigger the HTML to update its content.Without understanding too much of what your code is attempting to do, have html be a key of the state property.

```
constructor(){
  super()
  this.state = {
    html = []
  }
  //other initializations
}
```

Whenever you want to update the contents of html, call this.setState with the updated contents and this will trigger React to attempt to render any updated content.

```
  this.setState({
      html: //updated html
  })
```

Understanding state and props are a necessity when dealing with React so I would reccomend learning the core concepts so you are better able to handle issues where your HTML is not being re rendered with updated content.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html